# AutoMapper : Map both ways in Net Core 2 syntax

Tags: .net-core, automapper, .net-core-2.0

What is syntax to map both ways in AutoMapper Net Core2?
I need to map `ProductViewModel` and `ProductDto` both ways. This is not working,

Startup.cs

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration
(
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Models.ProductDto, Models.ProductViewModel>(),
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Models.ProductViewModel, Models.ProductDto>()
);

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather create a separate initializer and mapper. e.g here is my `AutoMapperStartupTask` class.

```
public static class AutoMapperStartupTask
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<ProductViewModel, ProductDto>()
                    .ReverseMap();
            });
    }
}
```

And Mapper

```
public static class DtoMapping
{
    public static ProductViewModel ToModel(this ProductDto dto)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<ProductDto, ProductViewModel>(dto);
    }

    public static ProductDto ToDto(this ProductViewModel dto)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, ProductDto>(dto);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   AutoMapperStartupTask.Execute();
}
```

Use in Controller

```
var dto = productModel.ToDto();
var model = productDto.ToModel();
```