# How to do the update into database when I'm passing DTO then converted to Model in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following PUT method for web api for updating the record. Since I've modified to incorporate the DTO and then converted back to model in order to save to the database, I have the following error:

*Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.*

I believe this something to do creating a **Activities class** below followed by `db.Entry(activity).State = EntityState.Modified;`

How do I update this one then. Any ideas?

```
// PUT: api/v1/Activities/5
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("api/v1/Activities/{id}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutActivity(int id, ActivityDTO activityDTO)
        {
            string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var category = db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId && x.Name == activityDTO.CategoryName);

            if (category == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Category not valid.");
            }

            if (id != activityDTO.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var activity = await db.Activities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(q => q.Id == id);
            if (userId != activity.UserId)
            {
                return BadRequest("No right access to update");
            }

            // Construct the activity from DTO
            activity = new Activity
            {
                UserId = userId,
                CategoryId = category.Id,
                Name = activityDTO.Name,
                Description = activityDTO.Description,
                NoOfMinutes = activityDTO.NoOfMinutes,
                DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            db.Entry(activity).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ActivityExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the new instance of the 'activity' class that's why changes are not reflecting while updating a record.

Please use below code it will work.

```
    activity.UserId = userId;
    activity.CategoryId = category.Id;
    activity.Name = activityDTO.Name;
    activity.Description = activityDTO.Description;
    activity.NoOfMinutes = activityDTO.NoOfMinutes;
    activity.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;

    db.Entry(activity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I'm on drug when I'm posting this should be just do this:

```
/*activity = new Activity
            {
                UserId = userId,
                CategoryId = category.Id,
                Name = activityDTO.Name,
                Description = activityDTO.Description,
                NoOfMinutes = activityDTO.NoOfMinutes,
                DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow
            };*/

            activity.CategoryId = category.Id;
            activity.Name = activityDTO.Name;
            activity.Description = activityDTO.Description;
            activity.NoOfMinutes = activityDTO.NoOfMinutes;
            activity.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;

            db.Entry(activity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to use AutoMapper if you're doing this stuff for multiple times!

Comment: @Div ... I should do that what I found it's quite complex to mapping DTO to Model and reverse as well

Comment: Nope, I don't think it is complex, all you have to do is, add nuget package, map your model and DTO and initialize on startup.

Comment: @Div ... how to map from DTO back to model in the code above ?

Comment: Refer this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592496/4753489

Comment: @Div I manage to mapped using the AutoMapper and you are right so easy. Managed to mapped source of model into DTO. Using slightly different method: ProjectTo(). BUT now back to original issue above from the DTO to model. `activity.UserId = userId;
    activity.CategoryId = category.Id;
    activity.Name = activityDTO.Name;
    activity.Description = activityDTO.Description;
    activity.NoOfMinutes = activityDTO.NoOfMinutes;
    activity.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;` How do I do that then?

Comment: Continuing: I'm using something like this: `private MapperConfiguration configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
          cfg.CreateMap<Activity, ActivityDTO>()
           .ForMember(dto => dto.OwnerName, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.User.FirstName + " " + ol.User.LastName))
           .ForMember(dto => dto.CategoryName, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Category.Name)));`

Comment: Then using it something like this in ProjectTo<>: `var activitiesDTO = await (db.Activities          .Include(b => b.User)          .Include(c => c.Category)         .Where(q => q.UserId == userId)          .ProjectTo<ActivityDTO>(configuration)          .AsQueryable()          .ApplySort(sortfields)          .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Hey, Please ask another question with all the detail, and give me a link, I will post the answer.

Comment: @Div see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982090/how-to-do-mapping-using-automapper-from-dto-to-model-both-put-post